# evaluate entered postcodes against perl array

Tags: regex, arrays, perl

I have an array which contains the starting 2 characters of postcode areas in perl like so:

```
@acceptedPostcodes = ("CV", "LE", "CM", "CB", "EN", "SG", "NN", "MK", "LU", "PE", "ST", "TF", "DE", "WS");
```

I have a search box where a user will type in part or a full post code.  I need to check if the post code they entered started with one of the elements of the array so for example if they entered 'CV2 1DH' it would evaluate to true and if they entered something like 'YO1 8WE' it would evalute to false as it doesn't start with one of the array values.

Now this would be easy to do in PHP for me but Perl isnt something im too good at and so far my efforts havn't been very fruitful.

Any idea peeps?

Comment: just to add its a .cgi script  not sure if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your list of accepted postcodes is large enough that performance in the matching code is an actual concern (it probably isn't), you'd probably be better off using a hash lookup instead of an array anyhow:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %accepted_postcodes = ("CV" => 1, "LE" => 1, "CM" => 1, "CB" => 1, "EN" => 1, "SG" => 1, "NN" => 1, "MK" => 1, "LU" => 1, "PE" => 1, "ST" => 1, "TF" => 1, "DE" => 1, "WS" => 1);
# Or, to be more terse:
# my %accepted_postcodes = map { $_ => 1 } qw(CV LE CM CB EN SG NN MK LU PE ST TF DE WS);

my $postcode = "CV21 1AA";

if (exists $accepted_postcodes{substr $postcode, 0, 2}) {
    print "$postcode is OK\n" ;
} else {
    print "$postcode is not OK\n";
}
```

This method will work fine with 5.8.8.

Comment: Good one, and is indeed fastest so far even with the small data set.

Comment: Even though the other solutions look great I went with this one simply because it worked without too much playing around.  The good thing is my data set of postcode areas is only about 12-15  so I shouldn't have any speed issues to worry about.    Thanks to eveyone for there answers.

Answer (score 5):

[**Smart Match**](http://szabgab.com/blog/2007/12/1198487688.html) (`~~`) is your friend here (after you use `substr` to get the first two letters from the entered string.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my @acceptedPostcodes = ("CV", "LE", "CM", "CB", "EN", "SG", "NN", "MK", "LU", "PE", "ST", "TF", "DE", "WS");

my $postcode = "CV21 1AA";

if ((substr $postcode, 0, 2) ~~ @acceptedPostcodes) {
    say "$postcode is OK" ;
} else {
    say "$postcode is not OK";
}
```

Comment: This is available only from Perl 5.10.

Comment: Versions of Perl 5 older than 5.10 have been EOLed, and 5.10 has been superseded by 5.12. I really wouldn't do new development against 5.8 today.

Comment: im sure this is a very silly question but whats the easiest way to find out which version im using?

Comment: ok it says This is perl, v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi  good or bad news?

Comment: Or just try to run the script and see if you get an error like "Perl v5.10.0 required--this is only v5.8.9, stopped at tmp/start.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at tmp/start.pl line 5."

Comment: hmm if i need 5.10.0 I dont have permissions to modify server to upgrade it from 5.8.8.  this was looking good too.

Comment: @SubstanceD — that is too old to use smart match. You can either use List::Util or upgrade. Upgrading doesn't mean you have to ditch the version you have currently installed. [Perlbew](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlbrew) lets you maintain multiple perl installs side by side.

Comment: I think i'll try the list util option first.  can the fi statement used in the example below be written in a slightly different fashion like if (first { $_ eq $code } @acceptedPostcodes){ print "Yes" } else { print "no" }  the reason I ask is I need to create a variable before returning true or false

Comment: Smart match isn't very performant, having to iterate through the whole list each time.  Since it's a static list, and you're going to do the work a lot, you're better off turning it into a hash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`List::Util`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html)'s `first`, or the `grep` builtin:

```
use List::Util 'first';

my $postcode = substr $input, 0, 2;    
my $status = (first {$_ eq $postcode} @acceptedPostcodes) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Marked it up cos it's right, but it benchmarks substantially slower than both foreach and ~~ solutions.

Comment: @JonB: `List::Util` is written in C for speed, so it will not be much slower than `grep/foreach/~~`.

Comment: I just tried them. It's a minimal benchmark but on 2000000 iterations I got approx 35 seconds for foreach and ~~ but List::Util hit around 60.

Comment: @JonB If I had to guess why smart match is faster, List::Util still has to run a Perl subroutine on each element.  Smart match can stay entirely inside C.  They both will stop when they hit the first element.  Smart match is so fast, the size of the array does not have a significant impact, 40 elements or 4 million, whereas List::Util slows down worse than linearly and must undergo the overhead of passing in the array.  If you have 5.10, use smart match.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, an old fashioned foreach version, note that it does a case sensitive match.
Benchmarked about the same as the ~~ version interestingly.

```
sub validatePostcode($)
{
  my ($testPostcode) = @_;
  my @acceptedPostcodes = ("CV", "LE", "CM", "CB", "EN", "SG", "NN", "MK", "LU", "PE", "ST", "TF", "DE", "WS");

  $testPostcode = substr($testPostcode, 0, 2);
  foreach my $postcode (@acceptedPostcodes)
  {
   if($postcode eq $testPostcode)
   {
    return 1;
   }
  }

  return 0;
}
```